# Which URL describes the resource the best?

Tags: http, url, rest, uri

```
/competitions/1/clubs/5/players
/players/search?club_id=5
/players?club_id=5
```

When should I use a first-class URL for a resource, and when should I use a nested URL?

**Update 1**

Thanks for the answers so far. I'll try to clarify things a little further.

Competition and Club have a many-to-many relationship. Clubs can participate in multiple competitions. I guess that would make Club a first class entity, so the way to access a club would be for instance:

```
/clubs/33
```

But I also need to be able to access clubs that participate in a specific competition, so I need something like this too:

```
/competitions/2/clubs
```

But someone mentioned it isn't recommendable to make a resource accessible via multiple URI's. Doesn't this violate that?

Also, I presume a URI like this would not be preferable:

```
/competitions/2/clubs/33/players/5
```

But rather use this:

```
/clubs/33/players/5
```

Club has a one-to-many relationship with Player.

Comment: It seems like the first URL should be `/clubs/5/players` for symmetry.

Comment: I changed the question because there is no such thing as a more or less RESTful URI.

Comment: I sent answer on your update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use path elements if the relation "feels" tree/directory wise (like club has players `/clubs/berlin/players`). Parameters are more "tags", I use it often for search-filters (e.g. defenders of 'berlin' club with age older as 22 `/clubs/berlin/players?position=defender&age=22`).

I design URL structure by 'domain-importance'. The most basic concepts should go to the root. If possible don't go too deep down url-structure, I try not to duplicate or create alias collections which represent identical resources (costs double maintenance in code + documentation).

Generally putting /clubs as root feels more natural: `/clubs/{club_id}/players`

I would only expose players through `/competitions/{comp_id}/clubs/{club_id}/players`, if players-set of is different as `/clubs/{club_id}/players`, e.g. during competition 
several players are blocked or didn't make it for the match-squad.

What do you mean with `/competitions`? Is it a tournament or a single match? If single match with two clubs maybe use home + away domain-concepts: `/competitions/{comp_id}/home-club` and 
`/competitions/{comp_id}/away-club` .

## Update-1 Answer

Here my thoughts on your  update-question:

I guess `/competitions/2/clubs` is a subset of `/clubs`, not every club is competing in every competition. So both resources are different, so two URLs are fine.

Thinking again `/competitions/2/clubs/33/players/5` should also be fine (but it is important that in server code duplication is avoided). This URL should even be mandatory when the returned resource is a subset of `/clubs/33/players` (e.g. players are injured or limit of team-size has been hit for specific competition).

Answer (score 1):

```
/competitions/1/clubs/5/players
```

<strike>As a URI is the identifier of a single resource, I would say the general rule is that if it is an object, it gets a 'first-class URL'.</strike>

I only tend to use the query parameters only when limiting/filtering lists, for example, `/competitions/1/clubs/5/players?gender=MALE`.

Comment: Path segments are used when identifying resources that can naturally be organized hierarchically.  Query parameters work for everything else.

Comment: @Darrel I'm not following how the OP given examples aren't hierarchical. Given the limited info we know, I see it as they want a list of players that belong to a particular club so it would fit to get the club then that club's players (`/clubs/5/players`). If it were me, that resource would be a list of URI's of players (`/players/1`, `/players/2`, etc). If that player resource representation contained information on which club/clubs they were in, then I would agree querying the players would be equally valid (`/players?club=5`).

Comment: I was just objecting to your general rule.  Consider a waypoint object on a map.  Wouldn't `/waypoint?latitude=47&longitude=56` be the most logical URI?  Regarding the OP's scenario, I would argue that clubs may not be specific to particular competitions, so the hierarchy breaks down.  What you really want to try and avoid is having two URIs that refer to the same resource.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put the ID numbers in the URL. They mean something only for those who actually knows what they mean, but for everyone else they are meaningless numbers.

You should always choose descriptive and related words for your URL, because the URL contribute to give informations about the linked resource.

Instead of using meaningless ID numbers, choose a unique name representing the name of the team or the competition, for example

```
/competitions/worldcup/clubs/usa/players
```

But if you really need to send that kind of anonymous data in the URL, then I would prefer to see them in a query.

Use only meaningful text for the URL.